# React Native https axios resquest gets Network Error on Android but not iOS

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, axios

I was building my react native application and using backend URL as http://123.123.123.123:port/ and everything was working fine while in development. but when I built my app and installed it on an android device it wouldn't work and I remember someone telling me that android by default only lets https request. so I changed the URL to the one that the web app is using which is https://example.com/api/... (not self-signed TSL certificate) and now the android can send requests but they all return as `Network Error`s (when built and when running on an emulator), but it works fine on iOS simulator. I'm new to app development and can't find any solutions online. Maybe there is an option that I'm missing?

My axios setup, that is sending the requests:

```
const customAxios = axios.create({
        baseURL: baseURL,
        timeout: 6000,
    });

...

const response = await customAxios.post('/login', {
        email,
        password,
    });
```

Error stack:

```
Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:81)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target-shim.js:818)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:574)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:388)
    at XMLHttpRequest.js:501
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:189)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:436)
    at MessageQueue.js:111
    at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:384)
```

The https URL is working on ios and web applications

Comment: which axios version are you using ?

Comment: "axios": "^0.19.0"

Comment: There is an issue in axios 0.19.0. If you downgrade to 0.18.0 then this issue will solve.

Comment: that didn't solve it

Comment: make sure you have `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in your manifest inside the `<application>` tag, and have these permissions added: 

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your manifest file add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` inside application tag.

```
<application
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">...
</application>
```

Comment: This was my problem too!! Had to add android:usesCleartextTraffic="true". Thanks!

Comment: @VLazzarova  consider ^

Comment: It was already there but https requests are not working in android. Only the http is working...

Comment: Hi, this is already have in my code `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" ` but still giving error can you please help me out?